# Parsing pflog files with Python

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap, openbsd

I'm trying to parse a pflog (OpenBSD 5.8) in Linux (Fedora 25) machine, with Python 3.5. I tryed the dpkt module, but [it doesn't support pflog files](https://github.com/kbandla/dpkt/issues/93). Then I tryed Scapy:

```
>>> p = rdpcap('pflog')
WARNING: RawPcapReader: unknown LL type [117]/[0x75]. Using Raw packets.
>>> p.summary()
Raw
Raw
...
Raw
>>> rdpcap('pflog')
<pflog: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:109>
```

As the warning message suggests, all packets are read as raw, so I'm not able to open them (and it's weird because [Scapy supports pflog](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/pflog.py)). I tryed different files (from the same OpenBSD machine) and the result is always the same. Also, I imported this file successfully in Wireshark.

My question is: how can I parse this type of file using Python? If Wireshark can open it without errors, some Python module should do it too (I think so).

Comment: Found a Python module that was able to read the packets using the Wireshark engine: [pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scapy works,
You need to use:

```
load_layer("pflog")
```

before loading your pcap

Comment: Thank you. I already parsed using pyshark module, but maybe Scapy will work better.